# Customized neural network Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am struggling to create a customized neural network in MatLab. I've made a sketch of my intended neural network.

[image]

To explain better how the network should work:

- Two input parameters (features) connected to the first hidden layer with two neurons (exactly equal to the number of input parameters)
- Each input parameter is connected to one neuron only.
- No bias in the first hidden layer.
- All the neurons in the first hidden layer are connected to the neurons in the second layer. There is a bias term in the second layer.
- The neurons from the second hidden layer is connected to one output.
- For simplicity, I did not show the projection functions in the plots.
  Could somebody help me with creating this (probably) simple customized network?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, mind sharing some code with us?

Comment: Sure, this is what I tried:
net = network;                                  
net.numInputs = 2;                              
net.inputs{1}.size = 1;                        
net.inputs{2}.size = 1;
net.numLayers = 2;                              
net.layers{1}.size = 1;                         
net.layers{2}.size = 3;                        
net.inputConnect(1) = 1;                       
net.inputConnect(3) = 1;
net.layerConnect(2) = 1;
net.outputConnect(2) = 1;

view(net)

The problem is that my output layer size is 3 and I doubt if I am doing it right.

Comment: @Pejmansho, what does that extra layer actually accomplish, given that in a normal network the inputs are going to have a weight applied to them before being fed to the neuron? In other words, what does `input*weight_1*transfer_function*weight_2` give you that you can't achieve with `input*weight`?

Comment: @beaker My main idea is to quantify the weighted inputs contribution to the network prediction. If I use a standard feedforward, all the inputs are connected to all the weights and it will be more difficult to decompose the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [feedforwardnet](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/feedforwardnet.html), in your example you have one layer of 3 neurons and an output layer but no bias on the neurons. For this you'll need to set up your network and change the `net.biasConnect` element

```
net = feedforwardnet(3);
net.biasConnect(1) = false;
view(net)
```

Once you train the network the rest will come into place.

Comment: Not sure if my explanation was clear. I actually need 2 hidden layers in which the second hidden layer is just a feedforward net, but the first layer is like a vector product of weights and inputs (so each input parameter should be linked to one weight). In your network all the inputs are connected to all neurons, right?